# angularjs - Sequentially call function that performs ngResource http post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post, ngresource

This is the outline of a function to perform and http post request to get all the entries from a table. This function is defined within my controller.

```
$scope.getAllData = function (tableName) {
  var allDataResults = $resource('/getAllDataForTable', {}, {
    save: {
      method: 'POST',
      timeout: 6000
    }
  });
  allDataResults.save($scope.all_data_input, function (response) {
    //Do stuff with response
    }
  });
};
```

I need to call this function sequentially for different tablenames. I tried simply calling it twice like this.

```
$scope.getAllData(tableName1);
$scope.getAllData(tableName2);
```

The second response comes in correct, but the first one is incorrect. Each response contains a list and the size of the second response's list is forced on the first one, causing the response to be incorrect. How do I properly chain these 2 post requests requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from your function, i. e.:

```
$scope.getAllData = function (tableName) {
  var allDataResults = $resource('/getAllDataForTable', {}, {
    save: {
      method: 'POST',
      timeout: 6000
    }
  });
  return allDataResults.save($scope.all_data_input, function (response) {
    //Do stuff with response
    }
  });
};
```

Then, you can chain your calls using the returned promise:

```
$scope.getAllData(tableName1).$promise.then(function() {
  $scope.getAllData(tableName2);
});
```

Btw the [`$resource` examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#examples) might help you understand it better. If you need to manage a lot of chained promises, you should look at [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).